# Closing WPF Application from a class library (Caliburn.Micro)

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I have to develop a WPF application and use Caliburn.Micro to provide MVVM.
But this time the view models are located in a separate class library.

All works fine, until I want to close the application. Because the view models are in a separate assembly, they can't access the applicatuion class of the WPF application. So I can't use System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown() to close the application, like I did in my former applications.

So how can I exit the application under this conditions?

Info about the existing class hierarchy: ViewModelBase is an abstract base class for all my view models. It derives from **Caliburn.Micro.PropertyChangedBase** and provides the functionality for IoC, the window manager and the event aggregator.

Comment: `System.Windows.Application.Current` is a **static** property... so why can't you invoke it in your separate assembly?

Comment: @IlVic Finally I figured out that three additional assembly references where missing, to make `System.Windows.Application.Current` working in the DLL assembly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inherit from `Caliburn.Micro.Screen`, which derives from `PropertyChangedBase` through `ViewAware`, and call `TryClose()`.

Or call just call `System.Environment.Exit(0)`.

Comment: TryClose() is working for Screen.
System.Environment.Exit(0) is working for Entire Application.